# django with jquery select values

Tags: jquery, django

Hello I need some help with intergrating django to jquery am not sure of how to go about it but I have given it an attempt.. I need when someone clicks the award placeholder depending on the value they have chosen the nominee placeholder displays the nominees nominated under that award from the database table called Nominee

Here is the form code:

```
    <form class="form-group" method="post" id="formsubmit">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>FOR AWARD</label>
                            <select name="award" class="form-control" id="award" required>
                                {% for name in award%}
                                <option>{{ name.award_name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label>NOMINEE NAME</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="nominee" id="nominee" required>
                                <option value=""></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

</form>
```

here is the jquery code

```
<script>
  $("#award").change(function () {// get the url of the `load_cities` view
    var award = $("#award");  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
    $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
      url: {%  url 'submit' %};
      // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
      data: {
        'award': award// add the country id to the GET parameters
      },
      success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
        $("#nominee").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

and the view handling it

```
def submit(request):

    award_name=request.GET.get('award')
    nominee=Nominee.objects.filter(‘award’=award_name)
    return render(request, 'panelist/home.html',{‘award’=award})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JsonResponse` instead of `render` so the response can be handled correctly through the AJAX success function.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def submit(request):
    award_name=request.GET.get('award')
    nominee=Nominee.objects.filter(award=award_name)
    return JsonResponse({'award': award})
```

Update AJAX success function to get the award value

```
...
success: function (data) {   
    $("#nominee").html(data.award);
}
...
```

Also, the "nominee" select tag should be changed to something useful in order to show the nominee value correctly. For example:

Use:

```
<span id="nominee"></span>
```

Instead of:

```
<select class="form-control" name="nominee" id="nominee" required>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: still not achieving what I needed the code is not submitting or returning any response to the view

Comment: Okay. There are different points to investigate. Do you know here where is the issue exactly so that I can help? Is it not submitting from your jQuery event or is it not receiving the request in Django, or is it receiving the request but cannot handle the response? Please debug your code via "print" or "console.log" and I am happy to support here.

Comment: Generally I can say that the code is fine except the part related to showing the nominee. What I understand is that you want to show the nominee as text only, so you have to change the nominee "select" tag to "p" or "span". I have updated my answer with that.